# Why there is not type safety in angular for DOM like there is in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

In typescript when we do this

```
let x = document.querySelector('a');
console.log(x.href);
```

we get error that `Object is possibly null`

but when i do the same for example in Angular ( we know that angular uses typescript ) in the component

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let x = document.querySelector('a');
    console.log(x.href);
  }
```

i don't get any compilation time error.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your Angular project's `tsconfig.json`. Older projects don't have the `"strictNullChecks": true` in the `compilerOptions` property. You have to set it manually.

Here you can read more about [all TSConfig options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) and [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where i can see the list of all this possible options for typescript configuration and the meanings of them ?